# Strange series that converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I'm trying to evaluate this series
$$S= \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_n \frac{\ln (n)}{n}$$
But I have some conditions on $a_n$ making the problem hard. Namely, $a_n=3$ for $n = 2 \mod 4$ and $a_n = -1$ otherwise.

Albeit 2 mod 4 =2 is just a number, a friend in the comments suggested that the 2[mod 4] takes values 2,6,10,... which of course makes sense. Meaning that $a_n$ will go like $(3 -1 -1 -1 +3 -1 -1 -1 +3 + ...)$ for $n=2,3,4 ...$.

I don't really know how to do convergence test when I have constraints on a summation constant like this. I have tried to rewrite the sum to a simpler form, tried to separate is at two sums for the two different $a_n$'s but I don't really know how to do it and there is where I'm stuck...

Comment: The problem would be probably harder if you had *no* conditions on $a_n$...

Comment: Where do you see $a_n = 2 \text{ } [mod 4]$ ? You said $a_n = 2$ if $n=2  \text{ } [mod 4]$...

Comment: Sorry! I meant that 2 mod 4 is just a number, and I don't really see the significance.

Comment: $n=2 \text{ } [mod 4]$ means that $n$ is of the form $4k+2$... So $n=2, 6, 10, 14...$ and so on. So here the sequence $a_n$ is (for $n \geq 2$) $3, -1, -1, -1, 3, -1, -1, -1, 3, -1, -1, -1, 3, -1, -1, -1, ...$.

Comment: Have you tried anything? It's not trivial that the series converges.

Comment: Fun fact: the sum is $\ln^22.$

Comment: @ProfessorVector  thanks! Actually, I was confused about the notation because I thought 2 mod 4 was just a number. Thanks for clarifying. 

I have only tried to evaluate the sum without $a_n$ which is silly of course, but I don't know where to start when we have constraints on $a_n$ like this. I have tried to re-write the sum, as well as separate it as two sums, but without any success.

Comment: @ProfessorVector genuinely curious how one sees that :)

Comment: I'm afraid you *still* don't understand *your* (?) question. $2 (\mod 4)$ is *not* a number, it's a residue class, containing (in this case) all numbers $4k+2$ for integer $k$

Comment: have a look at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3090911/evaluate-sum-limits-n-1-infty-1n-frac-lnnn

Comment: @ProfessorVector Sorry, that I understand now, so so far so good on that front. But my question was how you arrived at the result on what this series converges to :)

Comment: Your title is "Trying to...", but you didn't even try to prove convergence. You didn't say anything about the origin of the question. How can anybody know if you'll understand the answer?

Comment: @ProfessorVector thanks, I see.  This is my first ever post here and I appreciate the feedback. I did update it with what i tried. Hope the question is more clear now :) 
As you will see in the edit, numerically, I got that the sum converges to $ln^2(2)$ so what I want is to be able to show that.

Comment: This is just a small detail, but I'm getting a [different approximate value for the sum](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nh4nsgcro7). I've summed the first $10^8$ terms and I'm getting $0.480452921815$, not $0.48026$ as stated in the question.

Comment: @K.defaoite What value of $\ln^2(2)$ did you get?

Comment: This is question B-4 from the 2017 Putnam examination.  Two solutions and remarks are available here:  https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2017s.pdf

Comment: It was a good idea to calculate that numerically, to get some idea what's going on. As for convergence: the sequence $a_n$ is periodic with period $4$, and the sum over all values is $0$. That's why the sequence of partial sums $\displaystyle\sum^n_{k=2}a_k$ is periodic and thus bounded, so your series is convergent by Dirichlet's test, since $\ln(n)/n$ is monotone decreasing for $n\ge3$.

Comment: BTW, if we had $a_n=3$ for $n=4k$ instead of $n=4k+2$, the sum would be $\gamma\ln4-\frac12\ln^24$, where $\gamma$ is the famous Euler-Mascheroni constant. It's interesting that the term containing $\gamma$ cancels out in your case.

Comment: @WhatsUp See the link.

Answer (score 2):

If we're willing to play a little loose with the fact that this is conditionally convergent, we can use the fact that $3 -1 -1 -1 = (2 + 1) + (-1) + (-2 + 1) - 1$ to split the series into two alternating series:
\begin{multline}
S = \sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n\frac{\ln(n)}{n} = 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{\ln(2n)}{2n} + \sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{\ln(n)}{n}
\\= -\ln(2)\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)}{n} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{\ln(n)}{n} + \sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{\ln(n)}{n} = \ln^2(2),
\end{multline}
where in the last step we use the result that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n/n = -\ln(2)$.

As for proving the series converges, since $\ln(n)/n$ decreases monotonically, you should be able to use that show that the $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ of the partial sums are equal.

Comment: I just want to remark that this answer can be turned into a rigorous argument, by truncating the infinite sum at a certain bound.

Answer (score 2):

I found that the given sequence can be written as
$$a_n = \cos (\pi  n)-\cos \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right)-\cos \left(\frac{3 \pi  n}{2}\right)$$
and
$$\sum _{n=2}^{\infty } \left(\cos (\pi  n)-\cos \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right)-\cos \left(\frac{3 \pi  n}{2}\right)\right)\frac{\ln (n)}{n}=\frac{1}{2} \left(2 \ln^2 2+2 \gamma  \ln 2-2 \gamma  \log 2\right)=\ln^2 2$$

Answer (score 2):

As I pointed out in the comments, this is Question B-4 from the 2017 William Lowell Putnam competition.  For convenience, I am providing the first of two solutions provided from the link in my comment.  I take no credit--only minor changes to phrasing were made.

The key insight is to define an auxiliary telescoping series with terms $$a_k = \frac{\log k}{k} - \frac{\log (k+1)}{k+1},$$ for which we trivially have $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k = 0. \tag{1}$$  Since $a_k > 0$ for $k \ge 3$, we also see that $(1)$ is absolutely convergent.

Having constructed such a series permitting rearrangement of its terms, we next observe $$3a_{4k+2} + 2a_{4k+3} + a_{4k+4} = (a_{4k+2} + a_{4k+4}) + 2(a_{4k+2} + a_{4k+3}),$$ hence

$$\begin{align}
S &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(3 \frac{\log(4k+2)}{4k+2} - \frac{\log(4k+3)}{4k+3} - \frac{\log(4k+4)}{4k+4} - \frac{\log(4k+5)}{4k+5}\right) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (3a_{4k+2} + 2a_{4k+3} + a_{4k+4}) \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{2k} + \sum_{k=0}^\infty 2(a_{4k+2} + a_{4k+3}). \tag{2}
\end{align} $$

We next observe $$2(a_{4k+2} + a_{4k+3}) = \frac{\log(4k+2)}{2k+1} - \frac{\log(4k+4)}{2k+2} = a_{2k+1} + \left(\frac{1}{2k+1} - \frac{1}{2k+2}\right)\log 2.$$  Hence

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2(a_{4k+2} + a_{4k+3}) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{2k+1} + \log 2 \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{2k+1} + \log^2 2. \tag{3}$$

Finally, putting $(1)$, $(2)$, and $(3)$ together yields the desired result:
$$S = \log^2 2 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{2k} + \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{2k+1} = \log^2 2 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k = \log^2 2.$$

Answer (score 2):

This is not really an answer, but it's too long for a comment. I just wanted to share another possible direction one might take this problem. Our sum is
$$S=\frac{3\ln( 2)}{2} -\frac{\ln( 3)}{3} -\frac{\ln( 4)}{4} -\frac{\ln( 5)}{5} +...$$
But, we can regroup the terms as
$$S=\left(\frac{\ln( 2)}{2} -\frac{\ln( 3)}{3}\right) +\left(\frac{\ln( 2)}{2} -\frac{\ln( 4)}{4}\right) +\left(\frac{\ln( 2)}{2} -\frac{\ln( 5)}{5}\right) +...$$
So,
$$S=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left[\frac{\ln(4k+2)}{4k+2}-\frac{\ln(4k+3)}{4k+3}\right]+\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left[\frac{\ln(4k+2)}{4k+2}-\frac{\ln(4k+4)}{4k+4}\right]+\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left[\frac{\ln(4k+2)}{4k+2}-\frac{\ln(4k+5)}{4k+5}\right]$$
However using laws of logarithms and shifting our index one may instead state this as
$$S=\ln\left(\prod_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(4k-2)^{4k-2}}{(4k-1)^{4k-1}}\right)+\ln\left(\prod_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(4k-2)^{4k-2}}{(4k)^{4k}}\right)+\ln\left(\prod_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(4k-2)^{4k-2}}{(4k+1)^{4k+1}}\right)$$
The neat thing is that all of these products definitely converge, since they are all monotone increasing and bounded from above by $1$.
These products remind me of the somewhat well known product
$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^{\frac{1}{n}}}{(n+1)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}}=1$$
Perhaps somebody can say something meaningful about products of the form
$$P(a,b,c)=\prod_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(ak+b)^{\frac{1}{ak+b}}}{(ak+c)^{\frac{1}{ak+c}}}$$
I'm quite curious about this.